# pyo3 rust module kills Python on import

Tags: rust, pyo3

I'm writing my first Rust-based Python module, and it kills the Python process on import. I've got it down to a pretty minimal example, based loosely on the [html-py-ever example](https://github.com/PyO3/setuptools-rust/tree/main/examples/html-py-ever) (which does run for me without crashing).

I'm running Python 3.8 on an M1 macbook, Python is compiled for arm64.

```
% python -c "import platform;print(platform.machine())"
arm64
```

My output, reproducer command using the files pasted below. The install should take care of any python requirements:

```
(rust) jeremytemp@Jeremy-McGibbons-MacBook-Pro minimal % pip install -e . && python test.py
Obtaining file:///Users/jeremytemp/rust/minimal
Installing collected packages: minimal
  Attempting uninstall: minimal
    Found existing installation: minimal 0.1.0
    Uninstalling minimal-0.1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled minimal-0.1.0
  Running setup.py develop for minimal
Successfully installed minimal-0.1.0
zsh: killed     python test.py
```

src/lib.rs:

```rust
use pyo3::{prelude::*, wrap_pyfunction};

#[pyfunction]
fn foo() -> PyResult<u64>{
    let u: u64 = 1;
    Ok(u)
}

#[pymodule]
fn minimal(_py: Python<'_>, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(foo, m)?)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "minimal"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
pyo3 = { features = ["extension-module"] }

[lib]
name = "minimal"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
```

setup.py:

```py
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools_rust import RustExtension

setup(
    rust_extensions=[RustExtension("minimal.minimal")],
)
```

setup.cfg:

```
[metadata]
name = minimal
version = 0.1.0
license = MIT

[options]
packages = minimal
zip_safe = False
setup_requires = setuptools-rust >= 0.12.1;
python_requires = >=3.8
include_package_data = True
```

`minimal/__init__.py`:

```py
from .minimal import *
```

test.py:

```py
import minimal
```

pip freeze output is

```
(rust) jeremytemp@Jeremy-McGibbons-MacBook-Pro minimal % pip freeze
attrs==21.4.0
beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
certifi==2021.10.8
iniconfig==1.1.1
# Editable Git install with no remote (minimal==0.1.0)
-e /Users/jeremytemp/rust/minimal
packaging==21.3
pluggy==1.0.0
py==1.11.0
pyparsing==3.0.8
pytest==7.1.2
semantic-version==2.9.0
setuptools-rust==1.3.0
soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
tomli==2.0.1
typing_extensions==4.2.0
```

What am I doing wrong? Are there any steps I can take to get more helpful debugging output than "killed"?

Comment: Just came here to say I'm having the same problem. Also on M1. It's actually intermittent between builds. It seems to die with error code 137 which would indicate "out of memory" but that's all I've got.

Comment: After looking a bit more closely it looks like this might be an issue only when doing an editable install (with `pip install -e`). I'm wondering whether that's what you did also? If so, this is possibly a bug with `setuptools-rust`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a very satisfying answer, but the example executes fine on my windows machine. I'm assuming this is an issue with pyo3 on M1 Macs.